# Does the minimum amount of readiness ever change?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On my list of war assets, I can see the minimum amount of readiness required, indicated with a little bar. Does this value ever change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, minimum readiness threshold does not change throughout the game.